# Belt conveyor roller spring

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials, friction, conveyor

I wanted to know if anyone could help in this area.
I want to create an inclined conveyor belt where, when a cargo box reaches the top of the conveyor belt, the rollers sequentially move down (maybe with spring)to prevent the box from hitting or getting stuck, a design used in log flumes.

Comment: What rollers move down? To prevent the box from hitting what or getting stuck in what? "Log flume" = "an amusement park log flume"? A picture would be a big help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will upload a photo

Comment: How can i upload a photo

Comment: If you're trying to upload a photo in the comments, you can't. That's not where they belong so it's deliberately not doable. They belong in the question along with all the other missing details. There's an image upload button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: I didn’t find upload button

Comment: Did you hit the [edit] link below your question to switch it into edit mode? The  "Image" upload button icon is some mountains and the sun.